# Ajax Get Request Cors AND ERR_ABORTED 401 Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I have an API from trendyol.com (it is an e-commerce platform for Turkey)

When I try to get my products informations with api (it uses basic auth) I get CORS error (while dataType is "json"). If I change it as "jsonp", I get ERR_ABORTED 401 error. My auth informations are true, I am sure about this topic. Probably I have a problem about CORS. I am sending this request from my web page. (enginorun.xyz) I am not using chrome extension to ignore cors because if I develop my app with extension, will it work when I disable the extension. I am not sure. Please help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Trendyol Api Test</h1>
  </body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var url = "https://api.trendyol.com/sapigw/suppliers/supplier.id/products";

var username = "-";
var password = "-";


var settings = {
          'cache': false,
          'dataType': "jsonp",
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
       "credentials": "include",
          "url": url,
          "method": "GET",
          "headers": {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          "Authorization": "Basic -----",
              "accept": "application/json"          }
   }

      $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);

      });

</script>
```

If I use jsonp error;
[image: error image]

Comment: If you're hitting CORS, and you don't have control over the website you're connecting to, you're out of luck. That's the entire point of CORS

Comment: @freefaller but they share api with basic auth for customers

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header, not a request header.

Comment: Auth has nothing to do with it... if CORS is not set up on the target domain to accept incoming requests from the source domain, the browser will block it. Full stop. @jub0bs is right, it's a **response** header (i.e. the response from the target domain).  If you were able to set the header on the source, it would totally remove the point of CORS.  Only the target can say who can connect

Comment: You need to allow domain 1(Set a cors header for api) to accept cors request from domain 2 (enginorun.xyz)

Comment: @Shakti not exactly relevant, when requesting data from a 3rd party api you don't own.

Comment: What *exactly* was the cors error? The JSONP error is irrelevant, if the api doesn't support JSONP.